# Boost Python own module throws Segmentation Fault `GlobalError::PushToStack()`

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to wrap around an existing C++ llibrary we have for Python 3.6. I've followed the tutorials of Boost Python:

- https://flanusse.net/interfacing-c++-with-python.html
- https://www.mantidproject.org/Boost_Python_Introduction
- https://github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples/blob/master/01-HelloWorld/CMakeLists.txt

All of them SIGSEV, so I run the command under gdb:

`gdb --args python -c 'import MyPyLib'`

And the actual output is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff3bb02a9 in GlobalError::PushToStack() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0
```

I tried to run the `boost-python-examples` from Github and I get the same problem. If it helps, I'm on:

- gcc 7.4.0
- g++ 7.4.0
- python 3.6.8
- ibboost-python-dev 1.65.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, all examples use

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python)
```

But if you pay attention, there are two libraries in the system:

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep "libboost_python*"
        libboost_python3-py36.so.1.65.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3-py36.so.1.65.1
        libboost_python3-py36.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python3-py36.so
        libboost_python-py27.so.1.65.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.65.1
        libboost_python-py27.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so
```

So I started suspecting that my module was being linked to python 2.7 boost-python.
I swapped in `CMakeLists.txt` the actual component:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python3)
```

And now it works fine. It's quite surprising that such a miss-match throws such a cryptic error. Also `cmake` complains when using `python3` that no headers were found or indexed.

Comment: I had a similar issue (with the same segfault in `GlobalError::PushToStack`) when I added some dependency of my python module on an external C library, but forgot to link to it. Instead of bailing out with some missing symbol error, you get this cryptic error, and very little of a meaningful backtrace.

Comment: I am having a similar issue when using Cython. Any tips what might be the issue?

Comment: @skboro make absolutely sure the python library versions absolutely match. If they don't the ABI will throw sneaky errors.